# Check whether an activity is active or not from a different activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle, activity-finish

I have a flow in my application like this:

**For new users:**

Splash Screen --> Login Activity --> Home Activity

**For already registered users:**

Splash Screen --> Home Activity

Basically the **Splash Screen** has an if else to decide which activity to go to. Once a first time user logs in, his status is saved in a preference variable for the splash screen to decide next time not to open the login activity.

Now the situation is that. If a new user logs in and goes to the home activity, and then logs out. He is redirected to the Login screen which is pretty much what should happen. But, in case an existing user opens the app, he is shown the Splash screen and directly moved to the Home Activity. Now if the  user logs out, he gets out of the app. This happens because the Login Activity does not have any instance created and thus finishing the Home Activity finishes the whole app. Logout actually finishes the Home Activity, naturally the last active activity should open up. Which is not happening.

**What I want to do is that, I want to implement a logic which will check that the Login Activity is available or not. If its available then `finish()` will be called else the Login Activity will be called via intent.**

Please tell me how to achieve this.

**P.S: My app uses a custom theme with a customized action bar. If I call finish and Intent together or I use flags to clear existing activities then there is a weird transition effect which shows the black standard action bar for a split second thus creating a bad user experience.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when user login finish login activity and start home activity.
when user logout finish home activity and start login activity

Comment: I wish I could do that. I tried it, actually I am using a custom theme in my app, the theme also has a customized action bar, if I finish the activity and call another intent, then the transition is showing up a black action bar for a split second which will be a very bad user experience.

Comment: 1st start activity and than finish current activity, this want show blank action bar. try it

Comment: Hey friend, its not showing the action bar but its stacking the login activity

Comment: when u move from login to home just finish login activity, and when you logout just finish home activity and start login activity, it will work

Comment: I can not do that, because, there are certain activities and services dependent on the login activity, finishing it would sink the whole ship!

Comment: Than last way is to make object of activity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64854/discussion-between-ravi-and-kittu88).

Answer (score 2):

> Now if the user logs out, he gets out of the app. This happens because
>   the Login Activity does not have any instance created and thus
>   finishing the Home Activity finishes the whole app.

If i understood your question, why dont you just call the `Login Activity` manually after user click a `logout` button?

Its what i always did with apps that have flow like yours

Comment: Because, if the user is a new user, he already creates an instance of the login activity and if I call login activity again, then it is stacking the login activity. There will be multiple instances of the login activity which will disrupt the whole flow.

Comment: @kittu88 why dont you call `finish` everytime the login activity goes to home activity? So there will be no "multiple instances"

Comment: I wish I could do that. I tried it, actually I am using a custom theme in my app, the theme also has a customized action bar, if I finish the activity and call another intent, then the transition is showing up a black action bar for a split second which will be a very bad user experience.

Comment: @kittu88 i see..so you cant call `finish` anywhere? (since all activities using the custom theme)

Comment: @kittu88 it would be useful to update your question to tell your `custom theme` problem, so people can see it and help you better :)

Comment: I can call finish, that's not hampering. But I cant call finish and intent together.

Answer (score 0):

You always can call Login Activity via intent. If the activity is available, android will show this activity. Else android will create new activity automatically.
Actually that's why we use intents to show activity instead of creating activityes manually. System catches this intents and does all dirty work.

Comment: I have tested it the way you are suggesting and could notice stacking.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought that you afraid double creation of activities.
Then you need to use flags for intents. Such as FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. For more information read documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: That's really strange. Can you show your style code?

Comment: There is no style for ActionBar. May be you change style programmatically?

Comment: yeah // Set up the action bar
  ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
  bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#009945")));
  bar.setTitle("Study Story");
  bar.setIcon(R.drawable.statusbar_icon);

  int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
  TextView yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
  yourTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white_colour));
  yourTextView.setTypeface(TypeFaceController.titleFace(getApplicationContext()));

Comment: I think that's your problem. The code does not have time to work out. If you change style in xml, the system will immediately generate an activity with the desired style.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Hmm, but wouldn't you have the transition problem anyways? (If you were already logged in, and then log out - using intent/finish() you will have the same black action bar issue no?)

Maybe consider following ( I actually did this in my app):

Merge Splash screen and Login into one activity and depending whether you are logged in - display the login fields or proceed to home screen. Then you have a out of box consistent stack of activities regardless of use cases and no mambo-jumbo with do I already have this or not.

---

I can't comment because of I lack 4 rep, so I'll post as answer here:

I think @Blaze Tama is right. You can also use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP on intent to avoid stack flow problems:

From docs:

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

Comment: I wish I could do that. I tried it, actually I am using a custom theme in my app, the theme also has a customized action bar, if I finish the activity and call another intent, then the transition is showing up a black action bar for a split second which will be a very bad user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Always start Login activity and start Home activity right away if the user already logged in.

In the Splash Screen activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
If (user already logged in)
{
    intent.putextra("Logged in", true);
}

startActivity(intent);
```

In the Login activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null)
    {
        if (intent.getBooleanExtra("Logged in", false))
        {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, Home.class), requestCode);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // The existing code here
    }
}
```

In Home activity send back a code to indicate if the user logged out or just BackPress. If BackPress finish this Login activity.